# Why can we access properties of an instance created by a constructor?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

```
var Car = function () {
    this.wheels = 4;
};

var car = new Car();
console.log(car.wheels);
```

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to understand the concept of `scope`.

Here `Car` is assigned with a function which we call a constructor. And `var car = new Car();` creates a instance of a so called `Car` class.

I think `var car = new Car()` is actually creating a **function** and we use it to mock an **instance variable** in conventional OOP languages.

If that is right, `var car` should be a function and has its own 'scope' and we can not access its variables outside.

So why the last expression can get the value of `car.wheels` and print the value?
It is called from the global scope!?

Comment: No, it's not a function. What makes you think so?

Comment: @Oriol In JS functions are also objects. So car is an object without doubt. But I think beyond that it is a 'function' and it has its scope. So I think it's a function more specifically.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. "In JS functions are also objects" does not imply "In JS objects are also functions". `car` is not a function, `Car` is. `car` does not have any function-like behavior.

Comment: Why can it retrieve the thing you explicitly asked for?!! Because that's the sole reason they exist and the only thing that makes them Useful.   
`var car` is your *global* variable which refers to the object you've just constructed, and this object (who's handle is 'car') of course will have wheels property who's value is number 4.

Comment: @Oriol I agree that "In JS objects are also functions" is wrong. I think it is because I consider car is a 'function object' but not an 'conventional' object that lead to my original question. All I can think of is when `var car = new Car()` is executed, the function assigned to `Car` variable is called. And `car` is assigned with something. What happens when `new Car()` is executed? It doesn't return anything?

Comment: `new Car()` is more or less like `Car.call(Object.create(Car.prototype))`. See [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1646698/1529630)

Comment: @Jinglei.Y for additional information to Oriol comment writing `var car = new Car()` is similar to writing `var car = {wheels : 4}`, I hope you get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Questions:**

> I think `var car = new Car()` is actually creating a function and we use it to mock an instance variable in conventional OOP languages.
>
> If that is right, `var car` should be a function and has its own 'scope'
>   and we can not access its variables outside.

**Answer:**

These two statements are wrong because you are confusing `object`s and `function`s here.

**Explanation:**

In fact in your case `Car` is a `Constructor` which is also a `function`, but `car` in `var car = new Car()` **is not a `function` like you are saying but it's an `object`** created using the `Car` constructor, because the `new` keyword creates a new instance `object` using the `Car` constructor.

For example, if we write:

```
var today = new Date();
console.log(typeof today); //returns object

var reg = new RegExp('\\w+');
console.log(typeof reg); //returns object
```

We got two objects here because we used the `Date` and `RegExp`constructors to create two new objects.

**Difference between `object` and `function` in JS:**

To see the diffrerence between `Object` and `function`, run this snippet:

```js
var Car = function () {
    this.wheels = 4;
};
console.log("Car.wheels: "+Car.wheels);//You will get undefined

var car = new Car();
console.log("car.wheels: "+car.wheels);//You will get 4
```

Because `Car` is a `constructor/function` and its properties aren't accessible outside its scope but `car` is an object so we can access its properties.

Comment: But in JS functions are also objects?

Comment: Yes in JavaScript everything can be seen as an object, but if you write `var Car = function () {
    this.wheels = 4;
};` then `console.log(typeof Car);` you will get `"function"` .

Comment: @Jinglei.Y But not all objects are functions!

Comment: @Oriol Yes. I think you mean those basic types like numbers and strings, etc.

Comment: @Jinglei.Y Numbers and strings are not objects (and therefore are not functions). Number objects and string objects are objects (and additionally are not functions). But I didn't mean special objects like these, I mean the great majority of ordinary objects are not functions. `[]` is not a function, `{}` is not a function `new function(){}` is not a function, `/./` is not a function.

Comment: To correct you @Oriol objects **are not** functions, but I think you meant that in JavaScript we can create objects using a Constructor like this case but we can also create objects simply like this `var person = {name: "Ali", age:30};` but both of them aren't functions.

Comment: @chsdk @Jinglei.Y All objects are instances of a function.
`Object instanceof Function;   >> true;` &  `Object.constructor >> function Function()`. JavaScript is a  Functional Language.

Comment: I think I've misunderstood the `new` operator. I've just looked up the doc and it says **The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.** I thought it copies something, this is why I thought car is a function.

Comment: @BekimBacaj No in fact not all objects are instance of function, if you write `var Car = function (wheels) {
  var _wheels = wheels; // Function scope
    this.wheels = _wheels; // context
};
` then `Car instanceof Function` you will get `true`, but this works only with objects created using Constructors if you write `var person = {name : "John", age:14};` then `person instanceof Function` you will get `false`.

Comment: @Jinglei.Y Yes that's it. glad you understood it.

Comment: @chsdk Yes all objects are instances of a function; primitives and literals are not they are handled by the mediator, top-Object call for proper type constructor (which is a function just like any other constructor) in a second hand derivative Function > Object > Array chain. e.g.:  `[] instanceof Array >> true' > Àrray instanceof Object >> true` > `Object instanceof Function >> true`

Answer (score 1):

The properties you define on an Object with `this` or `prototype` is not private. They can be accessed and modified by possibly any function that has a reference to the instance. Read [this article](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) to get an idea of private variables in javascript.

The below example shows *one possible way* on how you can make `wheels` private and expose the `getWheels` function as a public `getWheelsPublic`. There are more patterns that is [documented here](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).

```js
var Car = function(wheels) {
  var privateWheels;

  function setWheels(wheels) {
    privateWheels = wheels;
  }

  function getWheels() {
    return privateWheels
  }
  setWheels(wheels);

  return {
    getWheelsPublic: getWheels
  }
};

var car = new Car(4);
var car2 = new Car(3);
console.log(car.getWheelsPublic(), car2.getWheelsPublic()); //4 3
console.log(car.privateWheels); //undefined
```

If you take a look at the instance you created in the result of below snippet (`{"wheels": 4}`), you can instantly see that wheels is available as a property in that Object and not associated with lexical scope of the function. Also notice that `privateOwner` in the lexical scope is not available from outside.

```js
var Car = function () {
    this.wheels = 4;
    var privateOwner = "SabithPocker"
};

var car = new Car();
console.log(car); //{"wheels": 4}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems you have a misunderstanding of my question. I know that instances can have their own properties. Actually my question is **why these properties are accessible from global scope as they are in a function scope of their own?** I think they are supposed to be local variables?

Comment: It is mainly because the properties defined by `this` in your case are added as properties on that `object` and is not private. It doesn't follow lexical scope. But variables declared with `var` will follow lexical scoping as you want.

Comment: So to answer the question, they are not in a function/lexical scope of `car` but just properties of car `object` which are accessible in all places where a reference to `car` is available.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that a function defines a scope and that all variables are local to it. However, functions have also *context*, which is what you access through the `this` operator. Context is object-based, and objects in JS are created by means of prototypes. In your example, the `function` acts as the constructor of the object, with `this` being the object context. So when you do:

```js
var Car = function (wheels) {
  var _wheels = wheels; // Function scope
    this.wheels = _wheels; // context
};

Car.prototype.getWheels = function(){
  return this.wheels; // Context
 }

var car = new Car(4);
var car2 = new Car(3);
console.log(car.wheels, car2.wheels);//4 3

console.log(car.getWheels())
```

you are using the context.

You can read more about this [in this article](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/).

Comment: Credit for the original snippet goes to sabithpocker, of course :D